# Data manipulation aggregating values by date in new row in R

Tags: r, aggregate, data-manipulation

I have a dataset which consists of three columns and 2000+ rows as below:

```
Dates         Last.Price Daily.Return
1 09.08.00    31.6875    -0.017441860
2 17.10.00    59.1250     0.002118644
3 24.10.00    50.7536     0.067584338
4 05.12.00    92.1250     0.011667811
5 04.04.01    42.0000     0.141304348
6 17.04.01    61.5100    -0.008702659
```

Now what I would like to do is to sort column 'Dates' and aggregate the daily returns (column 3) of each date in a new column. Additionally I want to divide the aggregated daily returns by the number of observations.
So if I have three observations on 01.01.00, let's say 0.1, 0.2 and 0.3. The result in the new column should be 0.1 + 0.2 + 0.3 = 0.6, then divide by 3 -> 0.2.

So far I tried to sort them as follows:

```
df$Dates <- lubridate::dmy(df$Dates)
dfsort <- dplyr::arrange(df, Dates)

num <- aggregate(Daily.return~Dates,dfsort,length)
names(num)[2] <- 'num'

aggrreturn <- aggregate(Daily.return~Dates,dfsort,sum)
names(aggrreturn)[2] <- 'aggrreturn'

merge(num,aggrreturn)
```

However this does not work unfortunately...

Glad for any help!

Comment: Sort by date, ascending, 01.01.2000, 02.01.2000, maybe I don't even need to sort these since I'm aggregating them below?

Comment: please privide your sample data using `dput`... Also, you'll probably get better answers if you include a desired result/ouput..

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What exactly do you want to do? Aggregating as you have done returns NAs.